# katapayadi sutra - some melakarta raagas' numberings that I can't understand

Tags: theory, indian-classical

The KaTapayadi system hinges upon the table below:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ka | Ka | ga | Ga | ~ga | ca | Ca | ja | Ja | ~ja |
| Ta | Tha | Da | Dha | Na | ta | tha | da | dha | na |
| pa | Pa | ba | Ba | ma |  |  |  |  |  |
| ya | ra | la | va | sha | Sha | sa | ha |  |  |

I have come to understand the numbering of the 72 Melakarta raagas are roughly as follows: The second consonant of the raaga name determines the first digit and the first consonant determines the second digit. E.g.,

1. kanakAMgi is the first, or the 01^th raaga. The first letter ka is in column header 1 so that's the second digit, and the second letter na is in column header 0 so that's the first digit, hence the raaga number is 01.
2. similarly chalanATa is the 36th raaga (cha for 6 and la for 3)

However, what throws me off is when one of the first two letters is a combination of consonants (vottAkShara in Kannada). E.g., kra, jyO, rya, Dva, etc. Because in such cases one of the consonants in the combination is preferred over the other. What precise rule is used to make this preference is still unclear. Could someone throw light on this?

On closely investigating, I find that there are 10 such cases:

- tna in ratnangi (raaga 02), between ta and na, na was chosen
- kra in chakravaka (raaga 16), between ka and ra, ka was chosen
- rya in sUryakAMti (raaga 17), between ra and ya, ya was chosen
- Dvi in ShaDvidamArga (raaga 46), between Da and va, va was chosen
- vya in divyamaNi (raaga 48), between va and ya, va was chosen
- shva in vishvaMBari (raaga 54), between sha and va, sha was chosen
- hma in sihmEMdramadhyamam (raaga 57), between ha and ma, ma was chosen
- rma in dharmAvati (raaga 59), between ra and ma, ma was chosen
- tra in citrAMbari (raaga 66), between ta and ra, ta was chosen
- jyA in jyOtisvarUpiNi (raaga 68), between ja and ya, ja was chosen

The rule involving such combinations is sure to be dependent on whether or not one of the letters in the combination is among ya, ra, la and va. However, I'm trying to determine the rule. Every rule I try fits at most nine of the above ten cases.

For example, I thought the following: If the latter consonant (one whose attached
vowel does not get snubbed) in the combination is among ya, ra, la, va, the former
(one whose attached vowel gets snubbed) should be preferred, and otherwise the
latter should be preferred. This worked for all raagas except the 46th one
ShaDvidamArga where the latter was preferred over the former, an exception to the
rule I thought held.

Any help answering above is appreciated.

Comment: We might be able to noodle out some of the rules based on the following spellings of Hindi words just looking plain wrong: "cha**rk**a", "Su**yr**a", "dha**mr**a".

Comment: Thanks for reminding though, the spelling as well occurred to me as a possible factor. But somehow can't nail it.

Answer (score 1):

When I pronounced them aloud I realised that the choice of consonant when two are involved in a single syllable is made according to the following rule:

The pronunciation involves a halved consonant (one which is not followed by a vowel) and a full consonant (one which is followed by a vowel).
E.g., in kra, the halved one is ka and the full one is ra.

There is a rule for all combined consonants with exception being the case where one of the consonants is ra. The rule is as far as I see, as follows:

> Rule: If in the pronunciation, the halved consonant is fully snubbed by the full one, we choose the full one. Else we choose the halved one.
>
> Exception: If one of the consonants is ra, we choose the other one regardless of its audibility in pronunciation.

E.g., in the question above

tna -> na (The outsider only 'hears' it with his/her mind's ear as he can see the tongue between the teeth and conclude that the halved consonant is a ta. You do feel something in the back of your throat as you say it but it's not heard outside. But if someone says to you over the phone, raknAngi, ratnAngi, raTnAngi, or rapnAngi, you can't tell whether he used a kna, Tna or pna or if he gave a pause after ra and then pronounced nAngi. This is what I mean when I say the halved consonant is FULLY snubbed.)

kra -> ka (the ka is clearly heard so we choose this)

rya -> ya (one consonant is ra)

Dva -> va (Da is snubbed totally, as is the ta in the syllable tna)

vya -> va (va is clearly heard)

shva -> sha (sha is clearly heard)

hma -> ma (this is also an anomaly as it is really pronounced as mha so the halved letter is ma and is clearly heard, one can definitely see the difference when hearing mha and hearing just ha)

rma -> ma (one consonant is ra)

tra -> ta (one consonant is ra)

jya -> ja (ja is clearly heard)

In short, in a syllable involving two consonants, whichever consonant is heard to the ear first is considered, exception is the case where one consonant is ra - in which case we choose the other consonant is regardless.

There must be some technical term for this snubbing effect, I encourage anyone enlightened enough to enlighten me on this and comment on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the Katapayādi sutra is correct in the simple scenario where there are no conjunct consonants in the first two syllables of the rāga name. For the more complicated scenario when there are such syllables, one should generally use the second component of the conjunct consonant. However, it turns out that some of the rāga names are an exception to this rule; possibly these rāga names were coined hurriedly. There are also more rāgas with conjunct consonants in their first two syllables than the ten that you have listed (see below).

From P. Sambamoorthy's *South Indian Music*, vol. 3 (2019 reprint, The Indian Music Publishing House), on page 46 (Chapter I: Rāga, § Katapayādi sutra):

> Where samyuktāksharas or conjunct consonant figure in the Katapayādi prefixes, the rule is, that the second or the last component letter of the conjunct consonant (i.e. the consonant immediately preceding the vowel) should be taken into consideration. Thus in Ratnāngi, Sūryakānta, Jhankāradhvani, Gāngeyabhūshani, Shadvidhamārgini, Shanmukhapriya, Dharmavati, and Kāntāmani, the correct serial numbers are obtained in this manner.
>
> But in the case of the following melakartas: Chakravāka, Divyamani, Visvambhari, Syāmalāngi, Simhendra madhyama, Chitrāmbari and Jyotisvarūpini, the first component letter of the concerned conjunct consonant has to be taken (as shown in the following table), in order that the application of the *katapayādi* formula might give the correct serial number.
>
> Thus these mela names were hurriedly coined and constitute an exception to the katapayādi rule.
>
> | Name of the melakarta | Number | Number after reversal |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | **Cha** **k**ra vaka | 6 1 | 16 |
> | **Di** **v**ya mani | 8 4 | 48 |
> | **Vi** **s**vam bhari | 4 5 | 54 |
> | **Śy**ā **m**a lāngi | 5 5 | 55 |
> | **Si** **m**henndra [sic] madhyama | 7 5 | 57 |
> | **Chi** **t**rā mbari | 6 6 | 66 |
> | **Jyo** **t**i svarāpini [sic] | 8 6 | 68 |